# When the same name is used for two or more methods in the same class

Tags: java

I need to do an assignment so i was strack in this Question in java

When the same name is used for two or more methods in the same class, how does Java tell them apart?

Comment: have you googled it?

Comment: on the basis of "method signature"

Comment: by theyr signature.

Comment: can you show with an example

Comment: Having multiple methods with the same name in the same class is called [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (<= click link for more information, there are also examples there).

Comment: google can show you millions of examples. I suggest you read the javadoc for the String class. it's a basic class and you should understand it, or at least read the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: thank you i have another question What do you call a constructor that accepts no arguments?

Comment: @MohammedKalimulla please Google for such a basic questions or try with basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can tell apart different methods by their method signature.

For example:

```
public void Write(String Name) {
}
```

and

```
public void Write(String Name, int number) {
}
```

would be two different methods in Java, and can be called like this:

Write("MineRocker");
Write("MineRocker", 1);

A more in depth answer can be found here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html